# How can I check the nature of critical point on three variable function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have study on multivariate calculus. What is the best way 
to finding the nature of critical point on a real-valued three a variable function?

In two variable function
we can use $$D = f_{xx}(x,y)f_{yy}(x,y) - (f_{xy}(x,y))^2$$ to check what is nature of critical point.

Thank you for all answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, for a non-degenerate critical point, you need to check if the [Hessian matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix) is positive definite (local minimum) or negative definite (local maximum). If the Hessian has both positive and negative eigenvalues the critical point is called a saddle point.